# Update rows in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Im trying to update a row in cakePHP 2.3.1.I have class Test extend AppModel with $validates array,
and the Controller( simplified ) :

```
public function editstudent()   {
    if($this->request->data)    {
        $this->Test->stuId= $this->data['Test']['stuId'];
        if ($this->Test->save($this->request->data))    {
            $this->set('state',1);
        }
    }
```

The book said that :

> Creating or updating is controlled by the model’s id field. If $Model->id is set, the record with this primary key is updated. Otherwise a new record is created:

As above I've set $this->Test->StuId but when I submit form it still shows :

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
>   SQL Query: INSERT INTO ........

As the error showed,the query still is INSERT not UPDATE
So what do I have to do to update,pls help me out :(

EDIT : @thaJeztah I've edit my view like this :

```
class Test extends AppModel {
var $name= 'Test';
var $primaryKey= 'stuId';
public $validate= array(.......);
}
```

But it still show the same problem

> Database Error
>   Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
>   SQL Query: INSERT INTO `cakePhp`.`tests` (`stuName`, `stuDoB`, `stuAdd`) VALUES ('Đào Đức Anh', '2013-03-25', 'Kim Liên')

As you see the query is still INSERT not UPDATE,can you help me why this still happens :(

Comment: What's the structure of your `tests` table?

Comment: 'tests' table have 5 field :

Primary key : stuId and 4 more field:stuName,stuSex,stuDoB,stuAdd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not following CakePHP conventions (see [CakePHP Model Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions), you will need to manually specify the primary-key and/or database-table to use for the Model;

```
class Test extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = 'studId';
}
```

Also, I wonder if 'Test' is a reserved name and may not be a proper name for the Model at all.

However, if this is a new project, I would **strongly** recommend to stick to the CakePHP conventions, they are there for a reason and will make life a lot easier when developing with this framework

**update**
Removed the `$useTable` property based on comment by the OP

Comment: I dont get your point.Cause as I know about cake convention,class Test extends AppModel will stick to table tests in the database,so I dont have to point it out like your code above ?

Comment: Ok, if your table is named 'test', you can remove the 'useTable' property, however, if your primary key is not called 'id' but' 'studId', then you should specify this.

Comment: That's mean cakePhp wont be able to detect itself what is primary key in my table right ? I didnt think about that,tks man .

Comment: That's what the conventions are for; by default, you should 'id' as the name for the primary key and use [modelname]_id as a foreign key to a model (e.g. `test_id`). Fieldnames should be lowercase, words separated with underscores.